# VBA Excel Macro for Text To Columns With User Input To Define Fields

Tags: excel

I'm trying to streamline a process i have multiple people do on a regular basis (with different levels of success hence wanting a system where everyone does it the same) involving quickly editing information. As part of this i want the macro (which is otherwise working fine) to use the convert text to columns function, however due to the variety of data i cannot use the delimited function, the variety again causes issues with the fixed width option as i cannot simply define the Arrays and apply them to every instance of the macro.
What i would ideally like is for the macro to do one of the following;

A Start the process and then present the user with step 2 of the convert to columns wizard so that the user can then define the columns correctly themselves before clicking finish and allowing the macro to carry on
OR
B Start the process and then present the user with step 2 of the convert to columns wizard so that the user can then define the columns correctly themselves before clicking finish and then clicking a second macro to continue the process

```
`Sub Compile()
'
' Compile Macro
' This macro copies the raw TRUST data from the "input" sheet into the "working" sheet where the data is    then converted into columns and formatted before being passed to the "output" sheet
'

'
Range("K12:K211").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Working").Select
Range("A4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("C4"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(30, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Range("C4:C1048576").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("I4").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("D4:D1048576").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("K4").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("E4:E1048576").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("J4").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("F4:F1048576").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("L4").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("G4:G1048576").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("M4").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Output").Select
End Sub`
```

Above shows the first phase of the macro (the rest all works but requires refinement once i get over the current issue) you can see the array values i set for the particular data being used on this test run, however these of course don't work when parts of the data are longer or shorter than these. as i say i can't use the delimited option as its not possible for the original data to be generated with a fixed marker for separation.
I've tried simply removing the "FieldInfo" line hoping excel would then ask for instruction but of course this did not work as the macro is not actually using the wizard

Sorry if i've not explained this very well but my head is fried, thanks for your time and i really hope someone can help solve this.

Thanks again,
Matt

UPDATE: Thought it might be useful to provide an example of the data

"3D32 NEWTNHTMD 04:31 CHESTER  05:46"

as you can see its broken down as code>location>time>location>time the times and code are always formatted the same way however the locations can be various lengths and many contain spaces (hence delimited spaces not being an option as it would create an extra column) the formatting of this data cannot be changed as it relies on a 30+ year old system which cannot be replaced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your pattern is always the same:

`code|location|time|location|time` and the times and codes are always formatted the same, why not just write a macro that does the splitting?

One way of doing that is with Regular Expressions.

[How to use Regular Expressions in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)

In the code below the splitted data is placed adjacent to the original, but you could make small modifications to have it overwrite or even be on a different worksheet.

Also, note that the `Time` data is being formatted according to my Windows Regional Settings default time format. If you wanted the same `hh:mm` format used in your original string, you can just add the number formatting code to the macro.

***Don't forget to set the reference as noted in the code below***

```
'Tools/References Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
Option Explicit
Sub splitIt()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim RE As RegExp, MC As MatchCollection
    Dim vRes(), v, i As Long, j As Long
    
'initialize regex
    Set RE = New RegExp
    With RE
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "^(\w+)\s+(.*?)(?=\s\d\d:\d\d)\s+(\d\d:\d\d)\s+(.*?)(?=\s+\d\d:\d\d)\s+(\d\d:\d\d)"
    End With
    
'Set to whatever the worksheet is
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet7")

'Assume range to process is a column that starts at A2
' with a column Name in A1
    Set r = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        v = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    Else
        MsgBox "No Data"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With

    ReDim vRes(1 To UBound(v, 1), 1 To 5)
    For i = 2 To UBound(v, 1)
        If RE.Test(v(i, 1)) Then
            Set MC = RE.Execute(v(i, 1))
            For j = 1 To 5
                vRes(i, j) = MC(0).SubMatches(j - 1)
            Next j
        Else
            vRes(i, 2) = "X"
        End If
    Next i
    
'write text to columns
Set r = r.Offset(columnoffset:=1).Resize(rowsize:=UBound(vRes, 1), columnsize:=UBound(vRes, 2))

'write titles
vRes(1, 1) = "Code"
vRes(1, 2) = "Location"
vRes(1, 3) = "Time"
vRes(1, 4) = "Location"
vRes(1, 5) = "Time"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With r
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    
'prevent conversion of codes that look like scientific notation
    .Columns(1).NumberFormat = "@"
    
    .Value = vRes
    
 'uncomment next two lines if you want to set the
 ' time number format different from default
    '.Columns(3).NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
    '.Columns(5).NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
    
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
End With
    
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, it gives me a really solid place to start from, i can strip it down a bit as i don't need the "write titles" section, the range is A4 to A203 and the offset is 2 columns, i've always only ever recorded macros rather than written them so would never have gotten anywhere attempting this method by myself whereas hopefully i can figure out some bits now

Comment: One problem i am having with it, maybe you can help further, some of the codes have an E in them e.g "5E01" excel recognizes this as scientific notation and so returns the result "5.00E+01" i thought if i added the line ".Columns(1).NumberFormat = "@" this would return the result as text and so keep it as "5E01" but instead it displays "50" which would be the standard notation. what formatting do i need to get the result to stay as "5E01"? Thanks again

Comment: @KidCreation You have the correct numberformat code. You've just put it in the wrong place. You need to set that **before** you write the data to that cell. So put that line immediately after `.EntireColumn.Clear`. I'll edit the code in my answer.

Comment: ahhh of course, so near but yet so far, that's another problem closed off, made loads of progress on this tonight, just a few more things to do before it'll be given some real stress tests, thanks for your help.

Comment: @KidCreation Glad to help. Since my answer seems to be what you require, kindly mark it as Accepted.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).